# Finding pairs of duplicates in a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm looking to find the number of duplicate **pairs** in a Java ArrayList.

I can work it out on paper but I don't know if there is some form of mathematical formula for working this out easily as I'm trying to avoid nested for loops in my code.

An example using the data set [2,2,3,2,2]:
0:1, 0:3, 0:4, 1:3, 1:4, 3:4. So the answer is six duplicate pairs?

Comment: Does the order of the numbers matter?

Comment: No, I guess it doesn't as I'm actually looking to execute functionality based on how many colliding pairs there are.

Comment: Should you have included `3:4` in the duplicate pairs?

Comment: Yes I should have done! Edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to count how many times each number appears (I would go with a map here) and calculate 2-combinations ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination ) of that count for each number with a count > 1.

So basically you need a method to calculate `n!/k!(n-k)!` with `k` being 2 and `n` being the count.

Taking your example [2,2,3,2,2], the number 2 appears 4 times, so the math would go:

4!/2!(4-2)! = 24/4 = 6 --> 6 pairs

If you don't want to implement the factorial function, you can use the ArithmeticUtils from Apache Commons, they already have the [factorial implemented](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html#factorial%28int%29).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid nested loops (at the expense of having 2 loops), you could:

1. for each number in the list, find how many times each number is repeated (maybe use a Map with key = number, value = times that number occurred in the List)
2. for each number in the map, calculate the number of possible combinations based on the times that it occurred (0 or 1 times = no duplicate pairs, 2 or more = n!/(2*(n-2)!) = (n*(n-1))/2 duplicate pairs)
3. sum all the possible combinations

Doing a sort like ElKamina suggests would allow for some optimization on this method.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the numbers first. Later, if there `k` copies of a given number, there will be `k*(k-1)/2` pairs from that number. Now sum it over all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), if your elements were `String`s:

```
Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create(list);
int pairs = 0;
for(Multiset.Entry<String> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
  pairs += IntMath.binomial(entry.getCount(), 2);
}
return pairs;
```

That uses Guava's [`Multiset`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) and [math](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/MathExplained) utilities.